# What strategy should I use to stop extreme data points scaling charts in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, scaling

I'm not sure what the term I'm looking for but here is an example.

Consider this chart

[image]

What I'm trying to do is stop the end data points Jan & Dec from making the rest of the data points flat/barely indistinguishable from each other.

What I want to do is to tell SSRS not scale the points in the end of the line - or something like that.

Edit: For Clarification:

I don't want to hide data points, I just want the extremes to not cause the the scaling of the other points to be affected. For example, if the average of the other data points is say 100, and the extremes are 5000, then I want the chart to scale to around 100 and the extremes to be scaled down. Of course I'll add data labels to show that they are way out of scale.

Comment: You would like to not see the first and second bar at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Scale Breaks** in SSRS Charts.

See [Add Scale Breaks to a Chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220529.aspx).

The major caveat is that you don't really have a lot of control if and when they appear:

> You cannot specify where to place a scale break on your chart. The
>   chart uses its own calculations based on the values in your dataset to
>   determine whether there is sufficient separation between data ranges
>   to draw a scale break on the value axis (y-axis) at run time.

So there's no guarantee they'll work as you desire even if enabled.

Still, it's worth considering. Set the property at the **Chart Axis** level:

[image]

Does a good job when they do work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out and see what it does for my data.

Comment: I won't be able to use this strategy but it's a good answer. If I don't get any more in the next few days I'll mark it as accepted, and once again thanks for the quick answer :-)

Comment: That seems like a fair deal! Scale breaks always *seem* great, but that fact that SSRS decides whether or not to apply them can make them difficult to deal with. Mucking around with report height and the specific Scale Break properties are the only options, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@Ian Preston] but there is some more control of scale breaks that is available. For example, you can create an expression for the `ScaleBreakStyle` Enabled property.  If I do something like the following, scale breaks only show up if the largest value of the Avg_Hrs field is greater than or equal to 6.  The other properties allow expressions too.  `MaxNumberOfBreaks` could be useful with an expression also.

```
=iif(Max(Fields!Avg_Hrs.Value) >= 6,True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Ian's comment about lack of control on `if/when` the breaks appear.

I have a chart inside a list grouped by a field called `CLIENTID`.  I have manually identified the `ClientIDs` that I currently want to use a scale break on and used this expression:

```
=iif(Fields!CLIENTID.Value=24 OR Fields!CLIENTID.Value=3 OR Fields!CLIENTID.Value=23,true,false)
```

If I wanted to get fancy I could use `TSQL` to get the two greatest values, then find out how far apart they are - the second one as a percent of the first one.  If the second is more than 300% (or whatever number) greater than the first one then set the enabled value to true, otherwise false.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: FYI for me it's not a SQL data source, rather it's SSAS but your answer is a good suggestion. Thanks anyway